# losing decimal precision in string filed when updating MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, decimal

I have a filed with `varchar(255)` data type. when I run this query :

```
update sample_tbl 
set in_order_real = in_order_real + 21.215541764099030466 
where id = 15
```

it removes extra decimals.

for example `in_order_real` number is `0` and when I run this query it keeps only some decimals and round up while it is a string field. how can i fix this issue?

Comment: If you are storing decimals in this field, why not use the decimal type, and save having to convert to and from varchar all the time?

Comment: @Akina I think this is because of mysql decimal limit. but my filed is a string data type. why mysql look at this like a decimal number? do you have any sample for cast?

Comment: @GarethD  because I don't know decimal section count. maybe 8 or 30

Comment: *I don't know decimal section count* It is enough to know its maximal possible value. For example, "it cannot be above 40".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must cast your string value to DECIMAL with proper precision.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sample_tbl (id INT, in_order_real VARCHAR(255))
> SELECT 15 id, 1.23 in_order_real
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 16, 1.23;
>
> SELECT * FROM sample_tbl;
> ```
>
> | id | in_order_real |
> | --- | --- |
> | 15 | 1.23 |
> | 16 | 1.23 |

> ```
> update sample_tbl 
> set in_order_real = in_order_real + 21.215541764099030466 
> where id = 15;
>
> update sample_tbl 
> set in_order_real = CAST(in_order_real AS DECIMAL(30, 18)) + 21.215541764099030466 
> where id = 16;
> ```
>
> > ```
> > SELECT * FROM sample_tbl;
> > ```
>
> | id | in_order_real |
> | --- | --- |
> | 15 | 22.44554176409903 |
> | 16 | 22.445541764099030466 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5c3b6bf3a64cdb6564b6fc96ba98a78)*

If you don't know actual decimal digits amount then use maximal possible value. Additionally you may trim trailing zeros in the result.

Answer (score 0):

`FLOAT` holds 24 significant bits -- about 7 decimal digits of significance.

`DOUBLE`:  53 and 16

So, putting 21.215541764099030466 into a `FLOAT` will garble the digits after about 7 digits:  ~21.21554.  For `DOUBLE`: ~21.21554176409903

Can't do arithmetic in `VARCHARs`; it is converted either to `DOUBLE` or `DECIMAL`.

Where do your numbers come from?  For money, use `DECIMAL(..., 2)`; for sensor readings, use `FLOAT`.